# Should the Azure Process IDs match what Visual Studio shows as Process ID on Azure?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, azure-web-app-service, remote-debugging

I am having a problem with remote debugging on Azure.  (It used to work.)  The problem is that I attached to the remote process but its not stopping at my breakpoints.  The breakpoints are a solid red so I believe things are correct.

I noticed the the PIDs do not match what Visual Studio 2017 displays and what the Azure Explorer Process shows and was wondering if that could be the issue.

[image]

Comment: Yes PID should be same. I believe the w3wp is crashing due to which PID is getting changed. You can verify this in Event logs with the message similar to 'Process is terminated'. Once this is fixed then I believe remote debug will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes PID should be same. I believe the w3wp is crashing due to which PID is getting changed. You can verify this in Event logs with the message similar to 'Process was  terminated due to unhandled exception'. Once this is fixed then I believe remote debug will work.

Every Azure web site has an **EventLog.xml** which is stored in **D:\home\Logfiles folder** in kudu. This eventlog.xml is a dump of Application Event logs and can be really useful in identifying runtime errors that occur on your web site.

[image]